# Setting variable values to be based on other variables

Tags: java, variables

Say we have variables `int a = 0;` and `int c;`.
Is it possible to make it so that `c` is **always** equal to something like `a + 1` without having to redundantly retype `c = a + 1` over and over again

Thanks!

Comment: No. This is not possible without encapsulating the behaviour somehow.

Comment: what if we use `c=a+1?`

Comment: Your question is simmilar to property idea. Property in pure Java is used by method getA() setA(v)

Comment: @orvi What I mean is like, it's equal to a + 1 without me always having to redundantly reassign the value over and over again

Comment: You could do it in a spreadsheet, but not necessarily in Java or similar languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible to make one variable track another variable. Usually, this is not desirable either: when a value of one variable is tied to the value of another variable, you should store only one of them, and make the other one a computed *property*:

```
int getC() { return a+1; }
```

A less abstract example is a connected pair of age and date of birth. Rather than storing both of them, one should store date of birth alone, and make a getter method for computing the current age dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have 2 variables tied in a specific way, consider using custom object to wrap `a` and `c` values. Then you can control the object state inside the class logic. You can do something like this:

```
public class ValuePair {

    private final int a;
    private final int c;

    public ValuePair(int a) {
        this.a = a;
        this.c = a + 1;
    }

    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public int getC() {
        return c;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you need mutability on the object, you can get rid of `final` modifiers on varialbes create the only setter like `setValues(int a)` which will assign both variables `a` and `c`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, The answer is no, you can't do it directly in **Java**, but you can redesign your `int` class, There is an example:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        MyInt myInt1 = new MyInt(1);
        KeepIncrementOneInt myInt2 = new KeepIncrementOneInt(myInt1);
        System.out.println(myInt2.getI());
        myInt1.setI(2);
        System.out.println(myInt1.getI());
        System.out.println(myInt2.getI());
    }
}
class MyInt { //your own int class for keep track of the newest value
    private int i = 0;
    MyInt(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }
    public int getI() {
        return this.i;
    }
    public void setI(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }
}
class KeepIncrementOneInt { //with MyInt Class to get the newest value
    private final MyInt myInt;
    KeepIncrementOneInt(MyInt myInt) {
        this.myInt = myInt;
    }
    public int getI() {
        return this.myInt.getI() + 1; //get the newest value and increment one.
    }
}
```

- Create your own `Int` class, because we need a **reference type** to keep track of the newest the value `a`. like the [MutableInt](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/mutable/MutableInt.html) in apache commons.
- Create a always increment `1` class with your own `Int` class as a member.
- In `getI` method, it's always from the `reference Int class` get the newest value `a`.